# Arabic Diacritization List

Tags: pronunciation, arabic

I wonder if there is any academical resource on the diacritization of Arabic words. Almost all Arabic text is written without diacritics and it is quite challenging to learn all the words.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking about the marks including the short vowel marks, gemination mark, and no-vowel mark, right? With names such as kasra, damma, sukun?

Comment: @hippietrail, yes, I'm asking for harakat marks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about the vowel signs (ḥarakāt)? What you need is a dictionary (the best one is Wehr) and a grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you know some arabic text resources with tashkeel marks, I can also use it to derive a diacritization list. As far as I observed, the words in Wehr dictionary don't have any harakat marks.

Comment: No, but the vocalisation is indicated by the Romanised transcription.

Comment: As for "Arabic text resources with tashkeel marks", what should I say? Qur'an, classical poetry, school books, dictionaries ....

Answer (score 1):

If you take me seriously I would suggest you to try some third grade books in Arabic countries. For two important reasons :

- A great pedagogical experts were involved in the preparation of such books
- They will ease tremendously your introduction into a completely new language's set of rules

After that you need to know that people have no magic at being able to guess words diacritics : you'll learn them almost unconsciously if you do one thing :

- Listen, Listen, Listen to a lot of Arabic (formel of course) in the documentaries, news, radios, just avoid using local dialects because they are different and may confuse you. Seek mainstream Arabic audios instead.

Perhaps, one rule that is general, is that there is a saying :
"العرب لا تقف إلا على ساكن"
which means Arab stops at a non diacritics letter or a letter that has 'soukoun', if you don't understand it now don't worry it is not the first thing to be learned neither.

Good luck!